# Installing Unity on RHEL 7 / Horizontal workspaces (Grid) on Gnome 3.14.2

Tags: rhel, gnome3, gnome-shell, workspaces, unity

My university has recently upgraded from RHEL 6 to RHEL 7 and it is a total mess.

It comes with Gnome 3.14.2 and I have been unsuccessful in getting the horizontal grid in the work-space. I have tried a couple of extensions (Flippery and workspace-grid) but that is of no use.

The extensions show up in the tweak tool and let me change the options for horizontal workspaces, but the workspace does not change at all. Is there any other extension I should try?

Also, Is there any way I can install unity on RHEL? I want to be sure that it can be installed without root privileges (I know the possibility is low).

This whole Vertical only workspaces are driving me crazy and are impossible to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

1. Download Workspace Grid Zip file from the [Git Repo](https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid-gnome-shell-extension)
2. Open the tweak tool
3. Go to extensions -> install extension (Select zip file)
4. Change the settings according to your needs.
5. Restart / Log out and in

My apologies, the second extension, Workspace Grid actually worked.

I think I had the Flippery Bottom Panel enabled while trying the workspace-grid extension.

Hence, it might not have worked. While cleaning up, I disabled Flippery Bottom Panel and left Wrokspace-grid as it is, and it worked.

I am leaving this answer here as it is, in case someone else needs it. If not, I'd be happy to take down this question.